# OutOfMemoryException while reading a file

Tags: c#, exception

In my application I am reading a file using a windows service. This service reads the file every second.
This is the code I am using to read the file:

```
public static byte[] GetBytesFromFile(string fullFilePath)
{
    FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(fullFilePath);
    try
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
        fs.Close();
        return bytes;
    }
    finally
    {
        fs.Close();
    }
}
```

After some hours I am getting a `System.OutOfMemoryException`. Am I doing anything wrong here?

**Update:**
I am using the returned bytes in this code:

```
object s = null;
System.Reflection.Assembly a = Assembly.Load(bytes);
object o = a.CreateInstance("ID_" + report.ID.ToString().Replace("-", "_"));

Type t = o.GetType();
MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod(name);
object[] values = new object[1];
values[0] = nameValue;
s = mi.Invoke(o, values);
return s;
```

Comment: TIP: Use Using() block on FileStream type. That way no finally or explicit Close call is required.

Comment: Is size of the reading file is constant or varies from time to time?

Comment: How big is the file that you are trying to read?

Comment: By the way, there exists a [File.ReadAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.100).aspx) method.

Comment: What is happening to the byte arrays after they are returned to the calling code, do they get kept in memory for a long time? If this code runs every second and you're not disposing of the byte arrays created by this method, memory will get filled up with time (especially if arrays are long)...

Comment: What happens with the returning `byte[]` in the calling code? Will it be stored in memory or be thrown away?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the edit, the problem is obvious:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly a = Assembly.Load(bytes);
```

Here's the thing: assemblies *do not unload* from an `AppDomain`. There are some garbage-collectible things like `DynamicMethod` - but not a full assembly. If you are loading assemblies, the only safe way to do that is into a separate `AppDomain` in the process. Then you can jettison the `AppDomain` when you are done with it (which unloads everything that is in it).

---

Actually, there is no guarantee that your existing code even *works* - `Read` does **not** guarantee to read all the data. I have a pending blog post about that...

But: if the files are big, it is likely you are slowly saturating the LOH, which is a non-compacting heap. The best advice I can offer is: don't read huge files into arrays. Try to re-write the downstream code to work with either a `Stream` API, some kind of "reader" API, or some kind of parsing iterator block.

Without seeing how the rest of the code processes things, it is hard to say more. However, it would be a good idea to run a memory profiler on the code to confirm that it is indeed the `byte[]` that are causing the memory issues.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "saturating"? Fragmenting?

Comment: @Marc, My files size is around 4KB. When I use VMMap tool,the private data is steadily increasing but CPU usage is around 2%. I updated my post to show where I am using the returned bytes. Could you provide some code sample for best way to implement this?

Comment: LOH = _Large Object Heap_, a special heap that is not garbage collected for objects larger than approximately 83 KiB.

Comment: @Sree ah, with the edit the problem is obvious... I will edit

Comment: Actually since .net 4.0 there are is a special kind of assembly that can be garbage collected: [Collectible Assemblies for Dynamic Type Generation (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd554932(VS.100).aspx)

Comment: @CodeInChaos AFAIK that does not apply to Load(byte[]) - I already mentioned the DynamicMethod usage - it looks like there are some other use-cases too, though.